# Oracle Duration Function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, duration

Why isn't my PL/SQL duration function working correctly?  In the query below, I manually calculate the 'hh:mm' the same way as in the function below.  However, I get different results.

Calling Query:

```
WITH durdays AS (SELECT SYSDATE - (SYSDATE - (95 / 1440)) AS durdays FROM DUAL)
SELECT TRUNC (24 * durdays) AS durhrs,
       MOD (TRUNC (durdays * 1440), 60) AS durmin,
       steven.duration (SYSDATE - (95 / 1400), SYSDATE) duration
  FROM durdays
```

Output:

```
durhrs:   1
durmin:   35
duration: '1:38'
```

Function code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION steven.duration (d1 IN DATE, d2 IN DATE)
   RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
   tmpvar   VARCHAR2 (30);
   durdays   NUMBER (20,10); -- Days between two DATEs
   durhrs   BINARY_INTEGER; -- Completed hours
   durmin   BINARY_INTEGER; -- Completed minutes
BEGIN
   durdays   := d2-d1; 
   durhrs   := TRUNC(24 * durdays);   
   durmin   := MOD (TRUNC(durdays * 1440), 60);
   tmpvar   := durhrs || ':' || durmin;
   RETURN tmpvar;
END duration;
/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you might have a small typo:

```
WITH durdays AS (SELECT SYSDATE - (SYSDATE - (95 / 1440)) AS durdays FROM DUAL)
                                                   ^^^^
SELECT TRUNC (24 * durdays) AS durhrs,
       MOD (TRUNC (durdays * 1440), 60) AS durmin,
       lims_sys.duration (SYSDATE - (95 / 1400), SYSDATE) duration
                                          ^^^^
```

Once this is fixed it works OK:

```
SQL> WITH durdays AS (SELECT SYSDATE - (SYSDATE - (95 / 1440)) AS durdays FROM DUAL)
  2  SELECT TRUNC (24 * durdays) AS durhrs,
  3         MOD (TRUNC (durdays * 1440), 60) AS durmin,
  4         duration (SYSDATE - (95 / 1440), SYSDATE) duration
  5    FROM durdays
  6  ;

    DURHRS     DURMIN DURATION
---------- ---------- ----------------
         1         34 1:34
```

Comment: Just needed a second set of eyes to look at it.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
sql>set time on
```

Then you will get the prompt like:

```
20:24:35 sql> select count(*) from v$session;

count(*)
-----------
78

20:24:50 sql>
```

Now you can come to know the query duration is 15sec's

Comment: In what way is this an answer to the question?